# What makes for good locations to go magnet fishing?

Tags: magnet-fishing

Magnet fishing is when you take go fishing with a magnet trying to find metal objects that people have lost into bodies of water such as cellphones, knives, bikes, etc.

What would make a location good for this?

Comment: @ab2 Its plenty popular in Europe, they have better luck since they have more concentrated people in smaller areas.

Comment: @ab2 It's true that in few areas of Europe, there may be enough munitions in the waterways to make magnet fishing inadvisable. But the whole continent is not a single, homogeneous weapons dump just waiting to go bang: the vast majority of areas are perfectly safe. Even if the whole of Europe *were* off-limits, a "US" tag still wouldn't make much sense, because about 90% of the world's non-European land area is outside the USA.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is that you are looking for places with **high human traffic right next to the water.** Places such as,

- Docks
- Fishing Piers
- Footbridges
- Paths next to a canal
- Boat ramps
- Old quarries

The depth of the water also matters, if its a seasonal canal or a in parts of the lake that are exposed when the levels go down it would be much easier to find them by looking instead of trying to catch them with the magnet.

Answer (score 3):

You have not added a location. Not to be a debby downer, but in the interest of other users that come across this post, I will add the advice given by a few Western-European governments:

"DON'T DO IT".

Although I find that a bit strongly worded, many Dutch, German, French, Belgian and Polish waterways do contain old WWII ordnance. That stuff is slowly deteriorating and a strong magnet that moves an element in the trigger mechanism may be just what is required for a little fireworks. A lot of tracer ammunition uses phosphor, which is likely to combust spontaneously if exposed to oxygen. A Dutch 12-year-old had a bit of a scare [recently](https://www.gelderlander.nl/arnhem/oorlogsbuit-magneetvissertjes-in-arnhem-ontbrandt-spontaan~aad76f8d/?referrer=https://www.google.com/)*. [This](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-06-26/exploded-world-war-ii-bomb-leaves-crater-in-german-cornfield/11247130)** is an extreme example of what decay may do: A large WWII dud bomb that was decaying in a field and exploded randomly. The same process occurs in smaller ordnance.

I would recommend that you read into the history of your local waterways - and those upstream - before magnet fishing. And if you find something funny, I would suggest that you call the cops.

Edit: I could not archive the sources, so I will describe the events below.

*On June 10th 2019, in Arnhem (Netherlands) two 12y/o's fished up 20pcs of ammo, dried it in the sun, at least one piece combusted spontaneously, left a hole in a bench. The kids had to be checked over by a medic because they might have inhaled the fumes.

**On June 23rd 2019 a 1.7-Richter tremor was registered near Ahlbach (Germany), was found to be a 500-pound WOII US/UK bomb. Left a 4m deep crater 10m wide in a cornfield. Other sources reported that this is a yearly occurrence.